# Deleting all files in a directory except the ones mentioned in a list

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a directory called a00 containing 3000 files with extension .SAC. I have a text file called gd.list containing names of 88 of those 3000 files. I am trying to write a code that will delete all .SAC files except those mentioned in gd.list

How to do that using shell/bash?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1):

If you are feeling brave, try something like

```
ls *.sac | fgrep -v -f gd.list | xargs echo rm
```

Note that I've put an `echo` in that `xargs`, just to make sure no one has a cut and paste accident.

Note also the limitations of this approach mentioned in the comments. As I said, if you are feeling brave...

Comment: Use of ls like this is always dangerous, as filenames may have spaces.
Also grep will tend to discard a whole row of filenames if there is 1 match.

Answer (score -1):

The `rm` command is commented out so that you can check and verify that it's working as needed.  Then just un-comment that line.

The `check directory` section will ensure you don't accidentally run the script from the wrong directory and clobber the wrong files.

You can remove the `echo deleting` line to run silently.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/me/myfolder2tocleanup/

# Exit if the directory isn't found.
if (($?>0)); then
    echo "Can't find work dir... exiting"
    exit
fi

for i in *; do
    if ! grep -qxFe "$i" filelist.txt; then
        echo "Deleting: $i"
        # the next line is commented out.  Test it.  Then uncomment to removed the files
        # rm "$i"
    fi
done
```

You can find the answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/830776/remove-file-but-exclude-all-files-in-a-list by L. D. James

Answer (score -1):

there are a few alternatives.

I'd prefer to see `find -Z` as it more clearly demarcates the file names:

```
find .  -maxdepth 1 -name '*.sac' -print0 | grep -x -z -Z -f gd.list | xargs -0 echo rm
```

Again, test this first. Perhaps sort the output and make sure it is unique versus the original file.

For a smaller list of filenames I would recommend just using find with -and -not -name and -delete, but with a larger list that can be tricky.

You could tag the files you want to keep as read-only, then delete the wildcard with the appropriate setting in rm or find to skip read-only files. That assumes you own the read-only flag. You could tag the files as executable, and use find, if the read-only flag is not for you.

Another option would be to move the matching files to a temp folder, delete the wildcard, then move the files you want to keep back. That is assuming you can afford for the files to disappear temporarily.

To make them disappear for a shorter time, move the kept files out to a temp directory, move the original directory out, move the temp directory in, then delete the movced out directory.